# When analyzing causality from X to Y, is IV regression better than Propensity Matching Score

Tags: regression, propensity-scores, instrumental-variables

When we are analyzing the causality from X to Y, especially when literature has used extensively IV regression and PSM as a method. However, as I know PSM is matching method while IV is a regression method. Can we use these methods alternatively? For example, my research question is how ill health (binary variable) is impacting labor outcome (binary variable). By going through literature I have found people have used both the methods and reported ill health has reduced or effect on labour force participation. However, I feel that IV regression method more appropriate when I want to report causal effect of ill health on labour than PSM. Please suggest me if I am wrong.